# Decorators in Meteor 1.4

Tags: meteor, reactjs, decorator, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am trying to understand how decorators work with Meteor 1.4. From what I [read](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6057#issuecomment-228532425), this feature is supported.

Now, I am unsure how to actually implement it. From [this blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.ayp4obod9), to decorate a class, I would require this code

```
export const TestDecorator = (target) => {
  let _componentWillMount = target.componentWillMount;
  target.componentWillMount = function () {
    console.log("*** COMPONENT WILL MOUNT");
    _componentWillMount.call(this, ...arguments);
  }
  return target;
}
```

Then use it as

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TestDecorator } from 'path/to/decorator.js';

@TestDecorator
export default class FooWidget extends Component {
  //...
}
```

The code compiles, but nothing gets output when the component is being rendered.

What am I missing? How do I implement a decorator in Meteor? Is this the proper solution? What is the alternative?

### Edit

I have tried this, and it still does not work

```
export const TestDecorator = (target) => {
  console.log("*** THIS IS NOT EVEN DISPLAYED! ***");
  target.prototype.componentWillMount = function () {
     // ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Decorators are a proposal, they are not part of ES7.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning your `componentWillMount` function to the class `FooWidget` instead of its prototype. Change that to `target.prototype.componentWillMount = …`. Besides, storing the previous `componentWillMount` is unnecessary in this case because it is `undefined` anyway.

Here is a [full working example](https://github.com/klaussner/decorator-example):

**main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>decorators</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

**decorator.js**

```
export const TestDecorator = (target) => {
  console.log('Decorating…');

  target.prototype.componentWillMount = function() {
    console.log('Component will mount');
  };
};
```

**main.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { TestDecorator } from '/imports/decorator.js';

import './main.html';

@TestDecorator
class FooWidget extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>FooWidget</h1>;
  }
}

Meteor.startup(function() {
  render(<FooWidget/>, document.getElementById('root'));
});
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Comment: That's strange. It worked when I tried it… will check again. :)

Comment: I've added an example to my answer (tested with Meteor 1.4). Maybe there's a problem with other parts of the code?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code (i.e. no errors in the console) as the layout is rendering normally, decorator or not. I also tried an alternative, using a wrapper to extend the `FooWidget` class (i.e. `class FooWidget extends TestDecorator(Component)`) and the alternative works! So, I have no idea why a decorator won't work. :/

Comment: I made a repo with the example above that definitely works in Meteor 1.4: https://github.com/klaussner/decorator-example (it outputs `Decorating…`, followed by `Component will mount` in the console). Maybe that helps you to isolate the problem. :)

Comment: This is the answer and a good example and was very helpful to me. An issue I ran into was the example Simple class decorator on Babeljs.io decorated my constructor and not the class. The above answer here worked as expected.